# Setting the RPM Package name in bdist_rpm

Tags: python, linux, centos, rpm

I am using Python setuptools for building a package. I would like to name the rpm built from `bdist_rpm` option to be different than the Python package name due to some naming restrictions.

Can it be done in the `setup.cfg` in the `[bdist_rpm]` section?

Answer (score 5):

The [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) tool makes easy to generate the RPM package and change the name or another parameter. By default, **fpm** makes the RPM with "*python-* prefix name, but the package name can be set with *-n* parameter. An example:

```
fpm -s python -t rpm -n my_package_name <python-source-library>/setup.py
```

Answer (score 3):

Well it is indeed a slightly non-standard and so not directly supported. You can however do `python setup.py bdist_rpm --spec-only` and this will generate a spec file inside dist/ named project.spec, starting like this:

```
%define name [name of your pkg as defined in setup.py]
%define version [version of your pkg]
%define unmangled_version [version of your pkg]
%define release 1

Summary: PyQt4 application to download trailers from www.apple.com/trailers
Name: %{name} # THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT TO CHANGE
Version: %{version}
Release: %{release}
Source0: %{name}-%{unmangled_version}.tar.gz
```

To succesfully build rpm from here you need to:

1. rename the spec file to [newname].spec
2. change every occurence of %{name} with [newname]
3. rpmbuild -ba [newname.spec] (after putting files in dirs where rpmbuild will find them)

I am sure you could automate this in some way if you really wanted to

Comment: your answer is a little bit incomplete. "after putting files in dirs where rpmbuild will find them" doesn't explain how and where run the rpmbuild command to finish the process.

Comment: It'd be handy to note that you change `Name:` instead of `%define name` because the define is apt to get used in the source package name as well, and the source package will (probably) have the "regular" name in the filename, not the overridden value (as demonstrated in the included example).  Which is why you don't actually change every occurrence - you just change the one `Name:` instance.